# Add a file into an existing Openshift configMap

Tags: jenkins, openshift, configmap

Is it possible to add a file into an existing Openshift configMap?

I'm to build a Jenkins job that would automatically update a specific key within an Openshift configMap, as this was suggested by me, but now I'm facing problems actually doing it. We can always have multiple configmaps, but for the sake of cleanliness my question still stands.

```
oc create configmap my-config --from-file=path/to/file.properties --dry-run -o 
yaml | oc apply -f -
```

I've only found this command to do it, but instead of adding the key "file.properties" and its contents as the value, it simply replaces my entire configMap with the key "file.properties", which is something I do not wish to do.

The use case here would be that some team deploys a specific configMap, and I sould be able to update and maintain the configMap with extra values, if possible.

EDIT: I've found [this](https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/users/2016-September/msg00062.html) thread from 2016, but `oc update` seems to have been removed from openshift 3.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get what I think you want by using json instead of yaml, and using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with its multiplication operator(`*`) which, when used with objects, will merge them recursively (split lines for readability):

```
oc export configmap my-config -o json \
  | jq ". * $(oc create configmap my-config --from-file path/to/file.properties --dry-run -o json)" \
  | oc apply -f -
```

While this works fine if you're looking for a one-liner, you could also manually edit the configmap in your text editor with `oc edit configmap my-config`, or `oc replace` (with a newly prepared json or yaml file), or by using the web console. It might be possible with `oc patch` also, but I wasn't able to get that working quickly.

Answer (score 2):

oc patch is your friend:

```
oc patch cm myconfig -p $(cat patch_file.yaml)
```

where patch_file.yaml has:

```
data:
  file.properties: |
    content of the file here
```

if file.properties is not in the cm it will be created and merged with the rest of the data, if it is in it will be replaced.

Comment: How if i want to replace file.properties only?

Comment: How if you've read the comment?
'...if it is in it will be replaced.'